# Скорость работы со статическими и динамическими массивами

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

Задался следующим вопросом. Есть ли разница во времени доступа к динамическому и статическому массиву? Создал максимально тупой пример, где создаются двумерные массивы. Один статический, а другой динамический. Записывал в элементы значение 1.2, так повторялось много раз, чтобы разница во времени была не на уровне погрешности. 
Код

```
const int column = 100;
const int line = 5000;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  double **matrix_dynamic = new double *[line];
  for (int count = 0; count < line; count++)
  {
      matrix_dynamic[count] = new double[column];
  }

  double matrix_static[line][column];
    clock_t start = clock();
    for(int step = 0; step < 10000; step++)

    for(int i = 0; i < column; i++)
    {
      for(int j = 0; j < line; j++)
      {
        matrix_dynamic[j][i] = 1.2;
      }
    }
    clock_t end = clock();
    cout << "DYNAMIC:\n";
    cout << (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "\n";
    for (int c = 0; c < line; c++) {
        delete[] matrix_dynamic[c];
    }

    clock_t start_static = clock();
    for(int step = 0; step < 10000; step++)
    for(int i = 0; i < column; i++)
    {
      for(int j = 0; j < line; j++)
      {
        matrix_static[j][i] = 1.2;
      }
    }
    clock_t end_static = clock();
    cout << "STATIC:\n";
    cout << (double)(end_static - start_static) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Результат получился следующим
Время работы для динамического 51.2 секунды, а для статического 44.8 секунд.

На сколько я знаю одномерный динамический массив создается последовательно в памяти, а двумерный получается разбросан по памяти?

Именно в этом смысле разбросан?

```
for (int count = 0; count < line; count++)
  {
      matrix_dynamic[count] = new double[column];
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В С/С++ есть только одномерные массивы. В вашем случае существенное отличие `matrix_static` и `matrix_dynamic` в том, что элементами `matrix_static` являются массивы double, а элементами `matrix_dynamic` являются указатели. Соответственно при обращении к элементам `matrix_dynamic` необходимо совершать один лишний переход по указателю.

Comment: Об этом не подумал. И правда...

Answer (score 2):

1. Все это сильно зависит от архитектуры процессора. Но для архитектуры x86 в плоской модели памяти разницы в доступе между статическим и динамическим массивом быть не должно.
2. В архитектуре x86 все массивы (и статические и динамические) любой мерности лежат подряд.
3. Странслируйте свой код так, чтобы транслятор выдал Вам ассемблерный листинг и посмотрите, в чем разница в доступе. Думаю, если включить сильную оптимизацию, то разница исчезнет.

UPD1:

> Соответственно при обращении к элементам matrix_dynamic необходимо
>   совершать один лишний переход по указателю.

А ларчик просто открывался. :-)